# ASP.NET MVC Controller - 500Error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, routeattribute

Why isn't my controller function called?
I always get 500error (in fiddler). I get no error in Visual Studio or an error site.

Controller:

```
[POST("/test1")]  // attributerouting (works with GET methods)
public ActionResult test1(TreeViewItemModel aItem)
{
  ...
}
```

Client:

```
var tree = $("#demo2").jstree("get_json");
var c = JSON.stringify(tree);
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/test1",
        data: tree,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are doing a post, not a get.  I think attribute routing works only with get. Does your action fire when you use the controller name as part of the URL?

Comment: Add an error handler for your ajax call and check the response there

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but as a side note routes with the route attribute are not supposed to start with a front slash.  The ajax url should still start with one however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was the data format:
solution:

```
public ActionResult test1(IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel> aItem)
{
}
```

Client:

```
var tree = $("#demo2").jstree("get_json");
var c = JSON.stringify(tree);
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/test1",
    data: c,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Some times `500 Internal Server Error` occurred because of syntax error in the View of it's controller like `{` or `}` mismatch or etc. Did you check syntax of `test1.cshtml`?

Comment: i have no View. i want to post data to server

Comment: Did you try checking post data using Firebug?